# How to bind json data in jquery without key

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to append data in table...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NebgH.png)

```
0
:
{createdBy: 1, UserName: "Anita Wilkins", 2018-02-01: "N/A", 2018-02-02: "N/A", 2018-02-03: "N/A", …}
1
:
{createdBy: 2, UserName: "Genson", 2018-02-01: "N/A", 2018-02-02: "N/A", 2018-02-03: "N/A", …}
length
:
2

__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Then come back and edit your question. It is currently not clear and too broad.

Comment: You'll have to give us a much clearer explanation of your problem, it's not obvious what you want or what the issue is. Also if you're talking about JSON, please show some actual JSON, the above is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate the array without knowing the key. The below solution would do it for you.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var tableData = [{
            "createdBy": 1,
            "UserName": "Anita Wilkins",
            "2018-02-01": "N/A",
            "2018-02-02": "N/A",
            "2018-02-03": "N/A"
        },
        {
            "createdBy": 2,
            "UserName": "Genson",
            "2018-02-01": "N/A",
            "2018-02-02": "N/A",
            "2018-02-03": "N/A"
        }
    ]

    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('createdBy', 'UserName', '2018-02-01', '2018-02-02' and 2018-02-03)
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        for (var key in tableData[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = tableData[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
</script>

</html>
```